# Выборка из MySql регулярным выражением

Tags: php, mysql

Поле `xfields` содержит текстовую информацию и среди него есть значение вида `...||filter_floor|1/9||area|30...`.Нужно вытащить все записи из БД, если запрос соответствует выражению. `filter_floor|1/9` означает первый этаж в девятиэтажном доме. Нужно получить например все записи, у которых этаж не меньше чем задано в фильтре.

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT p.id, p.autor, 
p.date, p.short_story, 
CHAR_LENGTH(p.full_story) as full_story, 
p.xfields, p.title, p.category, p.alt_name, p.comm_num, p.allow_comm, 
p.fixed, p.tags, e.news_read, e.allow_rate, e.rating, e.vote_num,
e.votes, e.view_edit, e.editdate, e.editor, e.reason 
FROM dle_post p LEFT JOIN dle_post_extras e ON (p.id=e.news_id) 
WHERE approve=1 AND allow_main=1 AND 
(xfields LIKE '%filter_type|Квартира%' AND (price >= '1' AND price <= '1000000000') 
AND xfields LIKE '%filter_floor_ot|5%' AND (price >= '1' AND price <= '1000000000') ) 
AND xfields LIKE '%filter_ragion|Жилпоселок%' 
AND xfields REGEXP "floor\|([0-5])\/[1-9]\|\| ORDER BY fixed desc, date DESC LIMIT 0,12
```

Ошибка:

```
Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp
```

В php это написано так:

```
'xfields REGEXP "floor\|([0-' . trim($_GET["filter_floor"]) . '])\/[1-9]\|\|"'
```

Comment: у вас последнее условие не закрыто в кавычки